# "Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'update'" when iterating over an array

Tags: javascript

I'm having problems with accessing objects' methods while iterating over an array that contains different types of objects. Both types of object have the specific method defined, but what I get is the TypeError with explanation: "Object 0 has no method 'update'". It doesn't matter what order I put the objects in the array. I am fairly new to js so probably I'm doing some incorrect reasoning based on other languages... I tested it in Chrome.

```
(function(){
    function Camera(){
        this.bar = "bar";
    };

    Camera.prototype.update = function(){
        this.bar +="bar";
    }

    function Object(){
        this.foo = "foo";
    };

    Object.prototype.update = function(){
        this.foo+="foo";
    }

    var camera = new Camera();
    var object = new Object();

    var array = [camera, object];

    for(o in array){
        o.update();
    }


})();
```

Comment: You're not typing `0.update` instead of `o.update` by mistake?

Comment: Probably not a good idea to overwrite `Object` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `o in array` then `o` refers to index of an array element. Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i].update()
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EDQPD/)
For more iformation about `for ... in` opeartor, review the [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Comment: `typeof([])` is `object`, Sir.

Comment: So? It's still bad practice.

Comment: **Never** saw this misbehaving, but thanks, I edited. Maybe you can give an example when such usage won't work properly?

Comment: thanks for the answer! I just used the loop you suggested in your answer's edit. using the for in loop was just a habit from Java...

Comment: The `For in` loop does not guarantee an order which usually is what you want or expect when iterating over an array. Also it lists custom prototype properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use .update like Evan Trimboli said because it's a method of Element. Rename it to something else and it'll work.

Comment: what Evan Trimboli said is probably true and I will certainly change the class name, just didn't know it was already used. However, the actual problem in this case was the index in the loop. After fixing that, it still worked despite overwriting Object